# How to select possibly non-existant row in a mysql join

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables that I need to join in a query that needs to return a single row. From one table I will be selecting a row that will always exist. From the second I need to select two rows, one of which will always exist and one which will exist only sometimes.

I can make this work in cases where both rows from the second table exist but not in cases where the second row does not exist.

Here's a simplified example of my schema

Table 1: COMPANIES

```
COMPANY_ID int

------------
|COMPANY_ID|
------------
|         1|
|         2|
------------
```

Table 2: PREFERENCES

```
COMPANY_ID int,
PREFERENCE_ID int,
PREFERENCE_VALUE varchar

-------------------------------------------
|COMPANY_ID|PREFERENCE_ID|PREFERENCE_VALUE|
-------------------------------------------
|         1|            1|             foo|
|         1|            2|             bar|
|         2|            1|             baz|
-------------------------------------------
```

What I am looking for is a query that will return a row with both PREFERENCE_IDs when COMPANY_ID = 1 and a row with one PREFERENCE_ID and on empty cell (or zero or any default value) when COMPANY_ID = 2.

I am trying to use a query like

```
select c.*, p1.PREFERENCE_VALUE as VALUE1, p2.PREFERENCE_VALUE as VALUE2 
  from 
    COMPANIES 
    join PREFERENCES p1 on c.ID = p1.COMPANY_ID 
    join PREFERENCES p2 on c.ID = p2.COMPANY_ID 
   where 
     p1.PREFERENCE_ID = 1 and 
     p2.PREFERENCE_ID = 2 and 
     COMPANIES.ID = 1;
```

When I run this query with COMPANY_ID = 1 (where there are PREFERENCE_IDs 1 *and* 2 it works fine. When I run it with COMPANY_ID = 2 it returns an empty set. I've tried using a left join for the second join but that doesn't change anything.

What I want it to return:

COMPANY_ID = 1 in query:

```
------------------
|ID|VALUE1|VALUE2|
------------------
| 1|   foo|   bar|
------------------
```

and for COMPANY_ID=2 it could return anything for VALUE2. null, blank, 0, I don't care:

```
------------------
|ID|VALUE1|VALUE2|
------------------
| 2|   baz|      |
------------------
```

TIA for any advice.

Comment: Why do you do this? Just `LEFT JOIN` the tables and get either one or two rows back. What could be more natural?

Comment: Because of the way the results are used in extant code and the refactoring that would be required to handle multiple rows. That's why I asked the question I asked and *not* the one you tried to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `WHERE` clause. `LEFT JOIN` will return nulls and produce exactly what you're looking for, but the `WHERE` in your query negates that.

```
select c.*, p1.PREFERENCE_VALUE as VALUE1, p2.PREFERENCE_VALUE as VALUE2 
  from 
    COMPANIES 
    inner join PREFERENCES p1 
      on c.ID = p1.COMPANY_ID and p1.PREFERENCE_VALUE = 1
    left outer join PREFERENCES p2 
      on c.ID = p2.COMPANY_ID and p2.PREFERENCE_VALUE = 2
   where 
     COMPANIES.ID = 1;
```

Comment: You don't even need  the p1/p2 references in the where clause... You can have them both left-join, but put the preference as an "AND" to the "ON" join condition.  Just leave the "companies.id = 1" in the where clause.

Comment: @DRapp you're right. I left out the `AND` on the join condition in my original response, and now that second portion of my answer is redundant. I've removed it.